# Checking Page Visibility and Page Focus for a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility

I want to make sure when a user is on the page.

Hence, when a user clicks on another window (looses focus) or changes tab, I should stop playing video on my page.

The problem is trying to do both simultaneously.

For example, through this JS plugin ([JQuery Visbility](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-visibility)), I am able to check whether the tab/window of my page is open.

Here's how it's doing it:

```
$(document).on({
          'show': function() {
            console.log('The page gained visibility; the `show` event was triggered.');
          },
          'hide': function() {
            console.log('The page lost visibility; the `hide` event was triggered.');
          }
        });
```

But it can't detect whether the page has focus or not. For example, the page might be open, but I may be opening another window separately and keeping my focus there.

The following code takes care of that (taken from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Msjyv/3/)):

```
function check()
{
    if(document.hasFocus() == lastFocusStatus) return;

    lastFocusStatus = !lastFocusStatus;
    statusEl.innerText = lastFocusStatus ? 'with' : 'without';
}

window.statusEl = document.getElementById('status');
window.lastFocusStatus = document.hasFocus();

check();
setInterval(check, 200);
```

Now, I am trying to do both simultaneously. Is it possible?

Comment: I suggest making use of page visibility API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API. It boils down to using `document.hidden`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event listeners for the `window`'s `focus` and `blur` events.

```
var hasFocus = true;
$(window).focus(function(){
   hasFocus = true;
});
$(window).blur(function(){
   hasFocus = false;
});
//check the hasFocus variable to see if the window has focus
```